# Flutter/Dart - Update Title Automatically on Built Page Views after edit?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, flutter-pageview

I've got a `PageView.builder` that returns pages. Each has a title and a tag.
I've also got an `EditPage`which allows the user to edit the title.
The edited title is updated via PHP on a MySQL database.
Can I get the individual page to automatically update with the new title?
Or do I have to completely rebuild the PageView each time I update the title?

Here's the `PageView.builder` code;

```
class StageBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<SpeakContent> speakcrafts;

  StageBuilder(this.speakcrafts);

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return PageView.builder(
      itemCount: speakcrafts.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, int currentIndex) {
        return createViewItem(speakcrafts[currentIndex], context);
      },
    );
  }

  Widget createViewItem(SpeakContent speakcraft, BuildContext context) {

    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              speakcraft.title,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              speakcraft.tagname,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

And here's the code for posting to the PHP/MYSQL database;

```
Future<String> titleUpdate({String opid, String title}) async {
  String upDateUrl;
  upDateUrl = "http://example.com?title=" + title;

  final response = await get(upDateUrl);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print(response.body);
    return response.body;
  } else
    throw Exception('We were not able to successfully update the title');
}
```

Comment: Use a list of keys, assign one to each page and call setState on the required page after edit.

Comment: Any chance of some example code?

Comment: Wrap your pages in a form like ```Form(key: formKey, child:myWidget()),``` and define formKey as ```GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = new GlobalKey();```

Comment: So in the above code I would wrap Column in that form?

Comment: Naw, you have to use a different key for each page so wrap ```createViewItem```. Pls make sure to use a list of keys. Like: ```List<GlobalKey<FormState>> formKey = new List(items); for(int i=0;i<items;i++) formKey[i] = new GlobalKey<FormState>;```.

Comment: createViewItem being a method won't let me wrap it. Where exactly should I wrap?

Comment: So I wrapped createViewItem (the return) and added List<GlobalKey<FormState>> formKey = new List(items); for(int i=0;i<items;i++) formKey[i] = new GlobalKey<FormState>; But I'm guessing "items" should contain something other than "items" cuz  Android Studio has underlined it in red.

Comment: My bad, I forgot that you don't have to initialize the list. It's syntax is: ```List test = new List<GlobalKey<FormState>>(speakCreafts.length);```. And your createViewItem looks like: ```itemBuilder: (context, int currentIndex) {
        return Form(key: test[currentIndex], child: createViewItem(speakcrafts[currentIndex], context),);
      },``` And yes, items is the number of createViewItems you have

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting, comments don't accept line breaks

Comment: RE: "comments don't accept line breaks" If you put the code into the "answer" button, I can accept it so you can get points.

Comment: OK, that code didn't throw any errors. Now how do I call the page to be rebuilt?

Answer (score 0):

The ListView's syntax is:
`List test = new List<GlobalKey<FormState>>(speakCreafts.length);`.

And your createViewItem looks like:

```
  return Form(
    key: test[currentIndex], 
    child: createViewItem(speakcrafts[currentIndex], context),
    );      
  },
```

And yes, items is the number of createViewItems you have.

To rebuild your page, you have to call the same setState with reference like:

```
test[index].currentState.setState(() {});
```

Thx for the points @Meggy! XD

Comment: Pls make sure to give a proper value to index. Preferrably call it inside the ListView where you can use currentIndex itself. It is okay to call outside too, just make sure you don't mix up the indexes.

Comment: How do I pass test[currentIndex] to the "EditPage" so that I can use it to call setState and rebuild the page upon a successful 200 response from my server?

Comment: Wait wait wait. Don't tell me you are not using futurebuilder? It just hit me now, coz I was thinking that you needed to ahh goddamn. Just look up FutureBuilder and StreamBuilder

Comment: And no, you can't pass currentIndex like that. I was thinking where you called your future coz you asked this question and it never occured to me that FutureBuilder is just what you need. It rebuilds the page after recieving the future. Sorry.....

Comment: So you're saying that "createViewItem" should be wrapped in a future and give the title and tagname as snapshot.data?

Answer (score 0):

Though not exactly what I wanted, in the end, I decided to allow the user back to the updated page through the appbar; The parameters I sent rebuilt a new page with just the one edited page.

```
 appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(
      "Back to edited page",
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 14,
        color: Colors.blueGrey,
      ),
    ),

    leading: new IconButton(
      icon: new Icon(
        Icons.arrow_back,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            PageTransition(
              type: PageTransitionType.downToUp,
              child: HomePage(stagetype: 'edit', currentaudioid: widget.opid,),
            ));
      },
    ),
   ),
```